# svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: svn

svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.app.xxx'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.

怎么破

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try https instead of http. Let me know if it solves your issue.